# Help with Circle in C

Tags: c, google-maps, coordinates

i'm trying to do something in C, I'm building a server that will receive a Latitude and Longitude coordinate, -23.0001, -43.3417 to be exact, i'm trying to make a 10km radius circle around that coordinate, is it possible ? I gave up trying to make a circle and was trying to make a square with 20km sides, where the coordinate I gave is the center, but I keep failing, here is what I'm trying

```
Quad *cria_quadrado_complex(Coords *b)
{
    Quad* a = (Quad*) malloc(sizeof(Quad));
    a->x1 = b->x + 0.0433;
    a->x2 = b->x + 0.0587;
    a->y1 = b->y + 0.0433;
    a->y2 = b->y + 0.0490;
    return a;
}
```

the structs used are:

```
struct coordenadas
{
    double x,
           y;
};

struct quadrado
{
    double x1,
           x2,
           y1,
           y2;
};

typedef struct coordenadas Coords;
typedef struct quadrado Quad;
```

those 0.0 something values are values I measured from google maps but they are faar from the center and dindn't work, is there a better way to do that ? help

ps -23.0001, -43.3417 are coordinates from google maps

here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
1---------- 1 : top coordinate of the square
-----------
-----C----- C : center coordinate (-23.0001, -43.3417)
-----------
----------2 2 : bottom coordinate of the square
```

1 and 2 I want to generate automatically with the center coordinates, they will be away from the center so the sides of the square is 10 km

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is possible, but you'll want to get the right formula.  A good start might be to read http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/gis-faq-5.1.html.

You don't say why you're doing this in C, and I can't tell if you need to calculate this for an arbitrary lat/lng or just for the one that you give.  If you can do it in another language or find a C library that will process KML, and if you only need the one set of coordinates to work, you can use the tool at http://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm to generate KML or a Google Maps Static API URL.  If you're only concerned about the single pair of coordinates you specify, a hardcoded KML file may be the way to go.

Comment: oh i'm doing this on C because i learn C on college and I'm using the functions i'm currently learning hehe

Comment: OK, I updated my answer, and included a link to a FAQ that gives you the formula for calculating lat/lng coordinates that are a specific distance from another lat/lng coordinate.  Implement that in C and you should be on your way to making a circle around a point.